# Learning parameters when loss is a piecewise function

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

I have a network to generate a single number $T$. I know in advance: a property of the loss function is that, when $T \in [a_1, a_2]$, the loss has the same value $L_1$; when $T \in [a_2, a_3]$, the loss has another value $L_2$; etc. The loss function resembles a piecewise function.

A concrete, simplified example of this problem is perhaps something like *object classification*. I have a set of objects, and their distances to a category $C$ that I want to classify these objects into. The distances are $[d_1, d_2, \dots, d_K]$. Assume without loss of generality that $d_1 \leq d_2 \leq \dots \leq d_K$. I want to learn a threshold $T$ for these objects that says, if the distance is near enough, then they belong to the category $C$; otherwise, they are not members of the category. For example, if $d_3 \leq T \leq d_4$, then objects $1, 2$ and $3$ (with distances $d_1, d_2, d_3$) belong to $C$.

What learning techniques I may use to learn weights of the network? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I will next combine the above network with other differentiable learning components, so ideally it would be good if the approach is compatible with gradient descent.

Comment: Could you please provide some concrete toy example of such a problem. Otherwise I cannot understand how is this different from a usual classification task? For example, in the case of two classes, 0 and 1, the loss is 1 when the label is misclassified, and 0 when it is classified correctly. From what I know, learning is usually affected more by the form of the activation function rather than by the loss values. A toy example would be helpful in clarifying the problem.

Comment: Hey Vladislav, could you kindly take a look at the problem now? I have added an example.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider Cubic splines to approximate your piecewise function.
[https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Cubic_Spline_Interpolation#:~:text=Cubic%20spline%20interpolation%20is%20a,Lagrange%20polynomial%20and%20Newton%20polynomial](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Cubic_Spline_Interpolation#:%7E:text=Cubic%20spline%20interpolation%20is%20a,Lagrange%20polynomial%20and%20Newton%20polynomial).
You can regularize your spline by adding continuity constraint on the first and the second derivatives at the nodes so the function would be smooth and would be a good approximation to your piecewise loss.